# How can I find the shortest path in a custom network that's on a map?

Tags: php, algorithm, maps, shortest-path

I have a huge network created with polylines and nodes placed on a map. (The lines do NOT necessarity overlay the roads on the map).

I'm trying to find the shortest path between two random nodes from the network but only using  the predefined polylines, and no the map roads.
I've been looking for a library with an efficient algorithm, but I couldn't find anything useful. (It has to be fast too, because it's a web app.)

Is there an 'easy way' to do this?

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There are tons of Shortest path algorithms consider taking a look at the following site and let me know if you have any questions: https://brilliant.org/wiki/shortest-path-algorithms/

Comment: @dawooshifingerhold Thanks! Actually I'm looking for one (or more) libraries to use in order to get the routing through my own network that's already on a map. Like routing with google maps from point A to point B but using my network and not google maps' roads. (My network is defined with polylines with lat and long). Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to write the algorithm from scratch in order for it to work on my network?